# How to read a file i have just written to

Tags: python, file

```
def createOutfile(text,lines,outfile):
    infile = open(text, 'r')
    newtext = open(outfile, 'w')
    count = 0
    newfile = ''
    for line in infile:
        count = count + 1
        newfile = newfile + "{0}: {1}".format(count,line)
    newtext.write(newfile)
    print(newtext)
```

I'm trying to take a file (`text`) and create a copy of that file (`outfile`) that just numbers the lines. The code i have now doesn't print an error but it gives me this:

> <_io.TextIOWrapper name='mydata.out' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>

If i replace `print(newtext)` with `print(newfile)` it gives me exactly what i want. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

To read a file's content you need to use its `.read()` method:

```
newtext.seek(0)       #Move the file pointer to the start of the file.
print(newtext.read())
```

Comment: Then it gives me this error : io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable
Any idea why that could be?

Comment: @user3330472 Ah! I didn't see that you've opened the file in `'w'`(write only) mode, use `'r+'` to open the file in read/write mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the output file in read-write mode,

```
def number_lines(old_file_name, new_file_name, fmt="{}: {}"):
    with open(old_file_name) as inf, open(new_file_name, "w+") as outf:
        for i,line in enumerate(inf, 1):
            outf.write(fmt.format(i, line))
        # show contents of output file
        outf.seek(0)    # return to start of file
        print(outf.read())
```

or just print each line as it is written:

```
def number_lines(old_file_name, new_file_name, fmt="{}: {}"):
    with open(old_file_name) as inf, open(new_file_name, "w+") as outf:
        for i,line in enumerate(inf, 1):
            numbered = fmt.format(i, line)
            outf.write(numbered)
            print(numbered.rstrip())
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is:

line 3: `newtext` contains the **file descriptor** of your output file.

line 5-8: `newfile` contains the **text** you want to output.

line 10: you print your file descriptor (`newtext`) and the outputed text (`newfile`).

At line 10, when you print the file descriptor (`newtext`), python displays the **representation** of this file descriptor:

the class name: TextIOWrapper

the name of you file: mydata.out

the opening mode: w

and the encoding: UTF-8

And when you print `newfile`, it displays the string you created just before.

If you want to read your file after writing in it, **you need to open it in read/write mode**: "w+":

```
>>> f = open("File", "w+")  # open in read/write mode
>>> f.write("test")         # write some stuff 
>>> # the virtual cursor is after the fourth character.
>>> f.seek(0)               # move the virtual cursor in the begining of the file
>>> f.read(4)               # read the data you previously wrote.
'test'
```